# Android room/TypeConverter issue while retriving list of objects

Tags: android, android-room

I am implementing a local cache using Room. I have created typeconverter to convert list of objects to json and back. But I am receiving mapping issue while retrieving data from json with error:

```
The columns returned by the query does not have the fields [title,media] in 
com.example.theApp.data.FlickrImage even though they are annotated as non-null or 
primitive. Columns returned by the query: [items]
```

Another one like this:

```
error: Cannot figure out how to read this field from a cursor.
private final com.example.theApp.data.Media media = null;
```

I tried other answers here but its not associated directly with this issue.

Here is my **typeconverter**:

```
class FlickrImageConverters {

@TypeConverter
fun fromImageListToJson(stat: List<FlickrImage>): String {
    return Gson().toJson(stat)
}

/**
 * Convert a json to a list of Images
 */
@TypeConverter
fun fromJsonToImagesList(jsonImages: String): List<FlickrImage> {
    val type = object : TypeToken<List<FlickrImage>>() {}.type
    return Gson().fromJson<List<FlickrImage>>(jsonImages, type)
    }

}
```

**Here is my entity class:**

```
@Entity
data class DatabaseImagesEntity(
    @PrimaryKey
    @TypeConverters(FlickrImageConverters::class)
    @SerializedName("item")
    val items: List<FlickrImage>)
```

**Dao class**
    @Dao
    interface ImagesDao {

```
@Query("select * from DatabaseImagesEntity")
fun getImages(): List<FlickrImage>


@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insertAll(images: List<FlickrImage>)

}
```

**FlickrImage class**

```
data class FlickrImage(val title: String, val media: Media)
```

**Media class**

```
data class Media(val m: String)
```

**LatestImage class**

```
data class LatestImages(val items: List<FlickrImage>)
```

Please let me know if you faced this issue and if you know the solution for this.

**Room database implementation**

```
@Database(entities = [DatabaseImagesEntity::class], version = 1, 
exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(FlickrImageConverters::class)
abstract class FlickrDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
abstract val imagesDao: ImagesDao
}


private lateinit var INSTANCE: FlickrDatabase


fun getDatabase(context: Context): FlickrDatabase{

synchronized(FlickrDatabase::class.java){
    if(!::INSTANCE.isInitialized){
        INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
            FlickrDatabase::class.java,
            "flickerImages").build()
    }
}
return INSTANCE
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was I was saving data in the wrong entity, wrong TypeConverters and as a result, I was using the wrong Entity class at the time of database creation.

Here are the necessary changes I had to make to store the list of objects:

**Flickr data class**

```
@Entity(tableName = "FlickerImage")
data class FlickrImage(
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
val id: Int,
val title: String,
@TypeConverters(MediaConverter::class)
val media: Media)
```

**TypeConvertors for Media class**

```
class MediaConverter {

@TypeConverter
fun fromMediaToJson(stat: Media): String {
    return Gson().toJson(stat)
    }

/**
 * Convert a json to a list of Images
 */
@TypeConverter
fun fromJsonToMedia(jsonImages: String): Media {
    val type = object : TypeToken<Media>() {}.type
    return Gson().fromJson<Media>(jsonImages, type)
    }
}
```

**DAO class**

```
@Dao
interface ImagesDao {

@Query("select * from FlickerImage")
fun getImages(): LiveData<List<FlickrImage>>
```

**Database class**

```
@Database(entities = [FlickrImage::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(MediaConverter::class)
abstract class FlickrDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract val imagesDao: ImagesDao
}


private lateinit var INSTANCE: FlickrDatabase


fun getDatabase(context: Context): FlickrDatabase{

synchronized(FlickrDatabase::class.java){
    if(!::INSTANCE.isInitialized){
        INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context,
            FlickrDatabase::class.java,
            "flickerImages").build()
        }
    }
    return INSTANCE
}


@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insertAll(images: List<FlickrImage>)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the appropriate annotations to your data class - e.g. for Gson you need to add the annotations `@SerializedName("field_name")` Otherwise, there's no way for the converters to know how to translate the json.

To clarify, the current annotations you have are only for Room. Just check with whatever json library you are using for the necessary logic.

Comment: I added annotations now to data classes fields but I am still getting same error.

Comment: please post your Room Database implementation class and your updated entity.

Comment: also, for your Dao class, switch from List<FlickrImage> to MutableList<FlickrImage> as MutableList's are both mutable and nullable. And you might need to add a `?` at the end for complete nullability. e.g.
`fun getImages() : MutableList<FlickrImage>?`

Comment: I updated the question with Room database. Please take a look at it.

Comment: Cheers. So a few things when looking at your error logs. It's unable to read the Media object - Room needs converters for any object thats not basic/primitive(i forget the exact details). So you'll need to create a TypeConverter for the Media object as well - the title field is a String so that's OK. Your Gson annotations need to go on all your different objects that are involved - which is just the Media object in this case. and Make all your data classes nullable. And since your data classes will be nullable, you want to make sure your getters in the DAO classes can handle null objects

Comment: I have implemented Typeconverter for Media but now I get this error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
    java.util.List<com.example.theApp.data.FlickrImage> images);

Comment: It has to be a fairly simple implementation I am so confused with this one.

Comment: please update your Entity class - I'll post an example above. Kotlin makes the implementation a bit trickier from my experience as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Entity(tableName = "images")
data class DatabaseImagesEntity(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        var id: Int? = 0,

        @TypeConverters(FlickrImageConverters::class)
        @SerializedName("item")
        val items: MutableList<FlickrImage>? = null
)
```

or

```
@Entity(tableName = "images")
class DatabaseImagesEntity {
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        var id: Int? = 0

        @TypeConverters(FlickrImageConverters::class)
        @SerializedName("item")
        val items: MutableList<FlickrImage>? = null
}
```

then update your DAO query to `@Query("select * from images")`

I named it images as an example - you can choose whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you @Zuko I am still working on it. I am using above snippet. I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

class ListConverter {

//from List to String

```
@TypeConverter
fun fromList(list : List<Object>): String {
    return Gson().toJson(list)
}
```

// from String to List

```
@TypeConverter
fun toList(data : String) : List<Object> {
     if (data == null){
         return Collections.emptyList()
     }

   val typeToken = object : TypeToken<List<Object>>() {}.type
    return Gson().fromJson(data,typeToken)
}
```

}